# How can I know which angular 2 version Im using?

Tags: angularjs, angular

In the browser's developer console with angular 1 I used to type:

```
angular.version.full
```

But do not work for angular 2.

Answer (score 5):

Agree Kévin Lemele.

The other way is the root component in your html has a attribute of `ng-version`.
Like this.

```
<app ng-version="2.3.0"></app>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this form of version indication is rarely referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

if you have the angular cli, you can do `ng --version` which will return something along the lines of:

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
node: 8.1.3
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.2.5
@angular/common: 4.2.5
@angular/compiler: 4.2.5
@angular/core: 4.2.5
@angular/forms: 4.2.5
@angular/http: 4.2.5
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.7
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.5
@angular/router: 4.2.5
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.5
@angular/language-service: 4.2.5
```

Answer (score 3):

you can see in packages.json your angular version.

```
"@angular/common": "2.3.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.3.1",
"@angular/core": "2.3.1",
"@angular/forms": "2.3.1",
"@angular/http": "2.3.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.1",
"@angular/router": "3.3.1"
```

if you have ^ before the version and run npm install command so you have the last angular 2 version.

Answer (score 2):

You can import the version of angular like this:

```
import {Version} from '@angular/core';
```

See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13162)

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code works well:

```
import {Component, VERSION} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'angular-version',
  template: `Version: {{version.full}}`

})
export class AngularVersionComponent {
   version = VERSION
}
```